# Burninate [slides]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

[slides](/questions/tagged/slides) has no tag wiki, and no clearly defined purpose, being currently used for:

- JavaScript slideshow plugin thingies {[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17442943/using-the-jquery-cycle-slides-more-than-once-on-the-same-page), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17233386/slides-js-portrait-orientation-image), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17214671/rotating-slides-of-information-on-a-website), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15422395/slider-showing-3-images-like-carousel-with-some-specified-details)} -> [slidesjs](/questions/tagged/slidesjs)
- [Sliding movements on a touchscreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17007363/how-do-i-implement-view-slides)
- [Sliding movement of `<div>`s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16435391/how-do-i-move-a-div-to-a-specific-coordinate-regardless-of-its-current-position)
- Anything related to PowerPoint {[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15936010/convert-ppt-pptx-to-jpg-png-using-php-on-apache-server), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15766931/using-vba-to-insert-update-image-in-powerpoint), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16233047/how-to-get-a-table-cell-in-aspose-slides), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16589892/how-good-is-the-ability-of-aspose-slides-to-create-pptx-files-with-templating)} -> [aspose-slides](/questions/tagged/aspose-slides)
- ["trackbars with more than one slide" (???)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15633083/multi-slides-in-a-trackbar)
- [Whatever this is...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15546457/css-and-html-only-tabs-not-responding-properly)

Given that it seems to be an information-free meta-tag, I vote burninate.

**Update**: See above list for possible replacement tags.

[image: Official burninate-request image]

Comment: There were only two questions with the tag.  Now there are none.  Should self immolate soon.

Comment: @Won't That's odd, I still see 57.

Comment: Hmm, I can see the tag is still on the questions you linked, however [the tag page says there are none](http://i.stack.imgur.com/tuUHh.png).

Comment: @Won't My research indicates that you might unwittingly be on the `frequent` tab. Try switching to `newest`.

Comment: My research says that this isn't expected behavior at all when clicking on a tag, and should probably be fixed ಠ_ಠ

Comment: We should be able to hand-burninate it. Go!

Comment: I can't edit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12112854/how-did-i-break-the-slide-of-slides-js; it contains a jsfiddle link without code, which I can't fix.

Comment: Here's another one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9992404/div-that-contains-jquery-wont-center-behind-another-div .

Comment: @michaelb958: Easy solution in cases like this, check it (the one with the fiddle link) now.

Comment: @Won't You pasted the fiddle code into the question. *\*self-facepalm\** I'll have to remember that one...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[It's gone.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/slides)

[image: Killed!]