# Tag question count seems wrong?

Tags: support, tags

I asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18086097/where-to-put-code-for-a-global-hardware-key-listener) question on StackOverflow, and its page says there are 36 questions tagged "smali". However, if I click said smali tag, it takes me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/smali), and says there are only 8 questions tagged with "smali". Am I missing something here, or is this a bug?

[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm not seeing this. Getting 36 in both.

Comment: @Mat [that would bring it down to 5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/smali+-android). Possibly a combination of other ignored tags.

Comment: Yeah, I see "36 tagged" in the top right part of the site too, and since I'm ignoring Android and Java, I see only 4 questions **actually displayed.**

Comment: Your second image is of the "Unanswered" tab where I also see 8. In the active tab there are 36.

Comment: @Madth Oh blimey, that's it. Mea culpa.

Answer (score 5):

You're looking at the "unanswered" tab, you silly git.

Comment: +1 for raging schizophrenia.

Comment: Note to readers: this happens with the `frequent` tab as well, as discovered [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187809/burninate-slides#comment577978_187809).

Comment: I don't think the UI made this very obvious. (...Yes, which is why I'm here.)