# Should the Faq-Link in Tag-Tooltips not point to frequent Tagged Questions

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, questions, frequent-tab

The faq-Link in the ToolTip of a Tag points to `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/[tag]?sort=faq`.

[image: Faq-Link in ToolTips]

Should the link not point to the frequently tagged questions of the tag `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/[tag]?sort=frequent.`

Cause currently when i click the link no tab is selected and it is not clear where i am. The parameter `sort=faq` and `sort=frequent` return the same results.

As an example use the [greenhopper](/questions/tagged/greenhopper).

The Faq points to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greenhopper?sort=faq (no tab is selected) what is the same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greenhopper?sort=frequent (frequent tab is selected) and the tagged questions count is 1. The total count of tagged questions is 92.

I also think that the frequent page should additionally display the total count of tagged questions and not only the count of linked questions.
I think this would reduce the amount of meta post, when new users state that there are zero tagged questions of a tag while there should be some. New users see zero tagged questions cause they are on the frequent tab and that is preselected if i was previously on it.

Comment: **+1** [This bit a burnination campaign once.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187809/burninate-slides#comment577978_187809)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed the link - it now both says "frequent" and goes to that tag.

Looks like this was missed when we moved faq to frequent.

With you in the next build.

---

So, that deals with the bug. Would you mind writing the feature request in its own post? Makes tracking these things easier... Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for fixing. Yes, i will move feature request to another post.